# Why Podman Desktop show stopped after starting Podman in shell?

Tags: podman

I'm confused by the inconsistency between the output in Powershell and what I see in Podman Desktop.
I run `podman machine start` successfully in Powershell but in Podman desktop it says "Podman is stopped". Also after restarting Podman desktop.
[image]

Are these states referring to two different instances of Podman or so?

Comment: I see that there is a ssh port conflixt message on the log. Maybe the podman desktop is not detecting that it's up due to it? Did you tried to click o run podman to see what happened?